# t-SQL Selecting a records where an event happened today accounting for midnight and timezones

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a table with a date column and time column and it gets populated whenever the user performs a scheduled task.  They generally have a 2hr window to perform the task and I can't seem to get my mind around how to see if that task was done today or not.

For example, if it is 12:30 AM, I need to check whether it was done at 11:30 PM on the prior day, or at 12:01 AM today.  I store all the time and dates as central time and have an offset number to adjust for other timezones.

Here is where I'm stuck, this works for something done last night, but not if it was done today after midnight (`@DatePartOfDateTime` is the date I am checking (it has already been corrected for timezone) and `@EndTime` is the time I am checking to see if it happened):

```
select 1 from tblMedsDispensed 
    where DatePassed = 
        case when (@EndTime = '23:59' or @Offset < 0 and @EndTime < '21:59') 
             and TimePassed < '01:00' 
             -- For midnight, if the time passed is < 01:00 then roll it back a day
            then dateadd(DAY,1,@DatePartOfDateTime ) 
        else @DatePartOfDateTime  end 
        and tblMedsDispensed.patdrugs_fk = tblPatDrugs.PatDrugs_id
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Adjust the time by the appropriate number of minutes or hours before doing the comparison with your desired date. It looks like you want to subtract one hour based on your comment in the code.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a guess. I don't think you need to mess around with all those variables and time components. What you want to do is sort of rotate the clock so that your logical start of day lines up with a calendar day so the date comparisons are easy.

```
select *
from tblMedsDispensed
where
    cast(dateadd(hh, @Offset - 1, DatePassed) as date) = cast('<literal date>' as date)
```

EDIT: I looked over your question again and I see you've got two columns. The idea here is the adjust the date value backward one day when the hour component is less than 1. I'm still not clear whether your tolerance is one hour or two hours.

```
dateadd(
    hh,
    case when hour(dateadd(hh, @Offset, <TimeColumn>)) < 1 then -1 else 0 end,
    <DateColumn>
)
```

Comment: Thank you Shawn, that got me headed in the right direction